# Why does my information extraction Python code get wrong output?

Tags: python

I have a csv file and I want to extract some statistical information,so I write a code to output the total number of each activities for each user ID,but the code just output the first ID's information correctly.Could somebody tell me what's wrong with my code?Here's my code and the wrong output.Thank you.

```
from collections import Counter
import csv
reader=csv.reader(file('F:\\HJZL\PythonData\log_train.csv','rb')) #read the csv file

list1=[]     #create an empty list
def static(i):   #information extraction function
  for line in reader:
       if line[0]==str(i):
           list1.append(line[3])  #add activities into list
  print 'ID:',i,Counter(list1)  #print the statistical information of ID i
  list1[:]=[]                    #clear the list
  return list1

i=1
while i<4:                      #get the statistical information of ID1 to ID3
    static(i)
    i=i+1
print 'end'
```

Why is information of ID2 and ID3 empty?

Comment: Where is the information of ID1?

Comment: What is the input? What is the actual output for that input? What is the *expected* output of that input? Please edit your question to include that information. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Oh, and why are you opening the CSV file in *binary* mode? That can cause problems with newline handling.

Answer (score 0):

`csv.reader()` objects read data from the underlying file object, and file objects have file positions that move from start to end as you read. If you want to read *again* you need to rewind the file pointer to the start:

```
with open('F:\\HJZL\PythonData\log_train.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # ...

    while i < 4:
        static(i)
        csvfile.seek(0)
        i += 1
```

However, it is better to just retrieve the information from your file *once*. You could just transpose your columns:

```
with open('F:\\HJZL\PythonData\log_train.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    columns = zip(*reader)

for i, col in enumerate(columns[1:4]):
    print 'ID:', i, Counter(col)
```